# Open url in previously opened window with same base URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

The requirement outlines a behavior for a solution that involves a list of links referring to URLs from multiple subdomains. Specifically, when a user clicks on the first URL in the list, it should open in a new tab. However, when the user clicks on the second URL, the behavior is more complex. The solution should check if the previously opened tab is for the same subdomain as the second URL. If it is, the solution should open the second URL in the same tab. If the previously opened tab is for a different subdomain, the solution should open the second URL in a new tab.

This requirement implies that the solution needs to keep track of the subdomains of the URLs that have been clicked by the user. It should also be able to differentiate between different tabs that have been opened, and know which subdomain each tab corresponds to. When a new URL is clicked, the solution should be able to match it to the correct subdomain and decide whether to open a new tab or use an existing one.

Tried using following Javascript but it seems not to work in all cases.

```js
// keep track of previously opened tabs
const openTabs = {};

// handle click event on link
function handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default link behavior

  const url = event.target.href;
  const subdomain = getSubdomain(url);
  const existingTab = openTabs[subdomain];

  if (existingTab) {
    // if tab for subdomain already exists, use it
    window.open(url, existingTab);
  } else {
    // if no tab for subdomain exists, open in new tab
    const newTab = window.open(url);
    openTabs[subdomain] = newTab;
  }
}

// extract subdomain from URL using regex
function getSubdomain(url) {
  const match = url.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?([^.]+)\./);
  return match ? match[1] : '';
}

// add click event listener to all links on the page
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

Comment: Please justify the negative point to the question

Comment: Basically, you cant really do that. Due to security and privacy reasons. Javascript will not be able to access the information of the tabs that has been opened. Which means for your requirement to `to match it to the correct subdomain and decide whether to open a new tab or use an existing one` is not doable.

Comment: if we keep track of open tabs, as I did in the sample code, I believe it should be doable.

Comment: The only time when you can access tabs information is when you are working with plugins/extension where you can then get all opened tab info with [tabs permission](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/).

Comment: Yes. You can track what url has been opened/clicked previously with your code. But you can only did it until the extend that you know that this particular URL subdomain has been opened previously. That's all. You will not be able to access the tab that has been opened previously and replace the tab url to the new url. You can open a new tab, but you will not be able to update/edit the url of a existing tab.

Comment: my code does works sometimes, but fails randomly

Comment: `window.open(url, target)` - the target is the "name" of the window/tab - it's a string.  This is the bit you need to store and reuse (not the return value).  If you use the same target, it will reuse that tab/window.

Comment: @JoshuaOoi *You will not be able to access the tab that has been opened previously and replace the tab url to the new url* - that's *exactly* what the `target` argument is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` parameter of [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) needs to be a string.

If the same string is used (and not one of the `_` specials), then the same tab/window will be reused for the new url.

Here's a simplified example

```
let target = "SO";
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75553310/open-url-in-previously-opened-window-with-same-base-url", target)
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com", target)
```

Unfortunately SO sandbox doesn't allow window.open, so here's the same in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cd8rqut5/)

---

Changes to your code require determining a value for `target` which you already do with `getSubdomain`:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const url = event.target.href;
  const subdomain = getSubdomain(url);

  window.open(url, subdomain);
}
```

Now all links with the same result from getSubdomain will open in the same tab and reuse that tab

*Whether it's a tab or window will depend on the user's settings in their browser and cannot be configured via js.*